# How to export the output (UIView) to an image of specified size in iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uiimageview, uiimage

I am saving the UIView as an image. When it is saved with the same size as the view, saved image is in good quality. But I want the image to be the size which I have specified but with good quality.

```
        UIGraphics.BeginImageContextWithOptions(ZoomLayout.Frame.Size, false, 1);
        this.ZoomLayout.Layer.RenderInContext(UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext());
        var imageFromContext = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIImage saveImage = imageFromContext;
```

ZoomLayout is the UIView I need to save as an image along with its subviews. Above code works fine. But I want the saved image size to be say (300x500).
 If I specify as below

```
         UIGraphics.BeginImageContextWithOptions(new CGSize(300,500) , false, 1);
```

Saved image is not in quality. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The third argument of the method `BeginImageContextWithOptions` is the scale of screen . So it will lose quality in some high screen densities (PPi) when you set it as `1` .

Actually , you need to set it as the scale of current device like

```
UIGraphics.BeginImageContextWithOptions(ZoomLayout.Frame.Size, false, UIScreen.MainScreen.Scale);
```

Comment: Quality of the image is achieved, but the Image metadata ExifImageWidth and ExifImageheight is not the one i have specified. I have given UIGraphics.BeginImageContextWithOptions(new CGSize(572,860), false, UIScreen.MainScreen.Scale);   But the saved image size is  (1536,1688). I want the saved image size to be (572,860)

Comment: How did you convert it ? I check the data of the UIImage and its' size is the value that we set .

Comment: UIImage size is the value which I have set only. But after saving when I check the saved image meta data thats height and width gets differ

Comment: Could you share your sample so that I can test it on my side .

Comment: Check the saved image in this site http://metapicz.com/#landing......Height and width of the saved image will differ from the specified

Comment: I think this because of the convert tool . I check the UIImage in folder and its' size is current .

Comment: No not the problem with converter tooI. I think the device you are using has the scale value 1 and that's why it retains the same size. I am using iPad it scales 2 times of the original dimension. If my original dimension is (500x500) with resolution 72 then saved image in iPad is  (1000x1000) with resolution 144 even though the underlying UIImage points to (500x500)

Comment: I tested on iPhone X (scale is 3)

Comment: Can you please share the original image and the one saved in iPhoneX so that it would be helpful for me to check in my end because I have stuck with that same problem.